# Installing over a messed up update

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, boot-partition

Have used Xubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 7 for the last years. Decided it was time to update. Accidentally closed the terminal window during an update executed via terminal. The OS (obviously) started looking strange : no window borders, etc.. Installed 17.10 on an USB key already. Now I'd like to install it on the partition where the messed up OS is, overwriting it, and keep the dual boot option with Windows 7. (Don't care about keeping the data on the old install partition) How do I do it? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is stopping you from plugging in your LiveUSB and installing 17.10 in the Linux partition?

Comment: @user535733 i'm asking for a safe way to do this without messing my dual boot. Should I format the partition first?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install Ubuntu on the disk partition just like you did install it on the USB stick.

Depending on whether you want or do not want to keep your data on the disk partition you should consider deleting it's contents:

- you could delete its contents by recreating the filesystem on that partition f.ex. with `mkfs.ext4`
- but then you'll of course loose or your data on that partition
- on the other hand you'll start with clean contents without any (useless) remains

As far as I know Ubuntu will preserver the Windows partition and boot (you should search for this on the internet), so you should be fine.